# Popup form returns 404 instead of updating DataTables row

Tags: jquery, datatables

jQuery 3.3.1
jQuery DataTables 1.10.19

I've set up a DataTable and some buttons that popup some forms to act against said table. Example: single-clicking on a row selects and highlights the row, then click the "Update" button pops up and populates the update-form. Making some changes and clicking the "submit" button I'd expect to see the row updated with the fresh information but instead the form goes away and is replaced by a 404 error.

```
function popupRuleDeck_update_submit() {
    var formJsonObj = $('#form_popupRuleDeck_update').serializeObject();
    var formJsonStr = JSON.stringify( formJsonObj);
    $.ajax({
      url: '/echo/json/',
      type: "post",
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      data: { json:formJsonStr, delay:3}
    }).done( function( response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      console.dir( "update succeeded textStatus:" + textStatus);
      ruleTable.row('.selected').data( response).invalidate().draw();
      ruleTable.row('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    }).fail( function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.dir( "update failed textStatus:" + textStatus);
      console.dir( "update failed errorThrown:" + errorThrown );
      var errors = jqXHR.responseJSON;
      if( errors) {
            console.dir( "failed errors:" + jqXHR.responseJSON);
      }
   });
```

Methinks I'm missing something at the end of my :done function

You can test out the functionality with jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kerchunk/wrLv1ce2)

TIA,

code-warrior

Answer (score 0):

I found insert and update both directly lead to 404 page. Please help confirm `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` is available from controller in AJAX URL attribue.
[404 page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0pj7.png)

Comment: Ugh. That's an artifact from my copy/pasting code from the live webapp, I'll need to mock it in the jsfiddle

Comment: I've mocked the URL to use /echo/json/ and updated the jsfiddle as shown above but still get the 404